# How to redirect links with htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess, apache2

For example i have a website example.com which has link to a file stored in example.org. So if user clicks download (default link is www.example.org/file.zip) I want to redirect him to third domain - example.net. Now in short:
www.example.com has link to www.example.org but when you click it you are redirected to example.net. Is this possible using htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question: Yes, it is possible. You are being vague, so you will want to make sure to customize the below solution to meet your real requirements. But essential it would be something like:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.zip$ http://example.com/{REQUEST_URI} [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I meant if I add in www.example.com a link like this:
<a href="http://example.org/file.zip">File</a> I want to redirect example.org/file.zip to www.example.net

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what .htaccess is for. [htaccess manual](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html)

Comment: Ok, I know I was very vague, because my 1st language is not English. I found what I was looking for:
AddOutputFilterByType SUBSTITUTE text/html
Substitute s/mysite.com/sitename.com/ni
Now I need to apply geoIP to this code. I was trying to do like this:
SetEnvIf GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE US LinkCountry
<IfDefine LinkCountry>
   #Substitute here
</IfDefine>
But It doesn't work. Substitution code without IfDefine works perfectly, geoIP also works good (I have tested it with deny from env=LinkCountry). Any ideas how to use If statement?